# Compare data in one table associated with a user ID to a 2nd table and list the values that the 1st table is missing from the 2nd

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table that looks like this (classes that students took):

| User ID | Course |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MATH101 |
| 1 | ENG101 |
| 2 | SCI101 |
| 2 | SOC101 |

And I want to compare them to a table that looks like this (a complete table of courses):

| Courses |
| --- |
| ENG101 |
| MAT101 |
| SCI101 |
| SOC101 |
| HIS101 |

To result in a table that looks like this (the courses that each student is missing based on the table of courses):

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SCI101 |
| 1 | SOC101 |
| 1 | HIS101 |
| 2 | ENG101 |
| 2 | MAT101 |
| 2 | HIS101 |

Comment: 1st cross join your unique list of students to a list of all classes.
then use a minus/except set operator to subtract from cross joined data set, the list of all student clases, those the students have taken

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.UserID, c.Course
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM Enrollments) s
CROSS JOIN Courses c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Enrollments e 
    WHERE e.UserID = s.UserId AND e.Course = c.Course
)
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/wp1bvkwZ

Additionally, in a well-designed schema there'd also be a separate `Students` table to use as a better starting point for UserID values the `SELECT DISTINCT` subquery. This would make it easier to add in columns like a student's name, and potentially make the query fast since the table would also likely have a better index for UserID.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH STUDENTS_COURSES(STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID)AS
(
  SELECT  1,    'MATH101' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 ,    'ENG101'UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 ,    'SCI101'UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,     'SOC101' 
),
AVAILABLE_COURSES(COURSE_ID) AS
(
  SELECT  'ENG101' UNION ALL
  SELECT'MAT101'UNION ALL
  SELECT'SCI101'UNION ALL
  SELECT'SOC101'UNION ALL
  SELECT 'HIS101'
)
SELECT DISTINCT SC.STUDENT_ID,AV.COURSE_ID
FROM STUDENTS_COURSES AS SC
CROSS JOIN AVAILABLE_COURSES AS AV
 EXCEPT
SELECT STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID
FROM STUDENTS_COURSES
```

Please try this one. The idea behind is simple

1. we get all possible permutations between courses and students (cross join part of the query)
2. from the step 1 we "substract" existing links course-student (part after except)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that *MATH101* and *MAT101* were meant to have the same value based on your desired output. Here is a working example using a right join from the list of distinct *User ID* values to the table of unique courses.

```
with Enrollments(UserId, Course) as (
  select 1,
    'MATH101'
  union
  select 1,
    'ENG101'
  union
  select 2,
    'SCI101'
  union
  select 2,
    'SOC101'
),
Courses(Course) as (
  select 'ENG101'
  union
  select 'MATH101'
  union
  select 'SCI101'
  union
  select 'SOC101'
  union
  select 'HIS101'
),
UniqueUsers as (
  select distinct UserID
  from Enrollments
)
select *
from UniqueUsers
  right join Courses on (
    Courses.Course not in (
      select Enrollments.Course
      from Enrollments
      where Enrollments.UserId = UniqueUsers.UserId
    )
  )
order by UserID;
```

Output:

| UserID | Course |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | HIS101 |
| 1 | SCI101 |
| 1 | SOC101 |
| 2 | HIS101 |
| 2 | MATH101 |
| 2 | ENG101 |